# How can I implement radio buttons with icons in Contact form 7?

Tags: plugins, forms, plugin-contact-form-7

I want to know how you can implement something like what is in the picture attached in Contact form 7, for now and seen what can be done with CSS 3 and HTML. But how can I implement it in the contact form?

This is the example in CSS 3:

https://dribbble.com/shots/3048587-Pure-CSS-Radio-Button-Tiles

[image]

Comment: ContactForm 7 outputs its own HTML for radio inputs, so basically what you have to do is take the methods from the SCSS, and re-write them so that they apply to HTML mark-up CF7 generates.